# Assign javascript variable to callback function with parameters

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

So, in one function I have:

```
function checkGoogleSubscription(params, response) {
    ...
    response.success(details);
```

I want to assign a variable in another function to that response, passing the parameters. Something like:

```
var details = function(checkGoogleSubscription(params).then(function(details) {
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, the parameters will be a dictionary, since it is more than one. I need to use the variable `details`, which will be the `callback` object from function one.

I don't even need a defined variable, just someway to use the callback from the other function.

**EDIT:**

Would this work?

```
checkGoogleSubscription(params).then(function(details) {
        // do something with callback from function one.
    });
```

Comment: I'm really not clear what you are trying to do. Your "something like" example event has unbalanced parens. It sounds like you are trying to use promises, but there is so much code missing from your question that it is hard to tell at what stage you have reached. You should read  [an introduction to promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) and then come back with a more well formed question if you still have a problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply. In function checkGoogleSubscription `response.success(details)`, I'm returning the object `details`. What I want, is to use this object in function 2. So I call function checkGoogleSubscription, pass parameters, and get that details object back. this is what I want. @Quentin